# Default CNI in Minikube

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, flannel, cni

I try to understand the Kubernetes network and I am now wondering if a CNI is used per default when installing Minikube and when yes which one?

In other words, can I run Minikube without a CNI provider like Flannel or Calico?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default Minikube runs on Docker default bridge-network, so the answer should be yes. You have to separately install other CNI providers, like Flannel.

For specific networking requirements, [Minikube docs](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/) could be checked out.

Comment: Could you please add a link where you found this info? I did not see it in the docs.

Comment: can someone add the link where this is explicity mentioned, i didnt seem to find it anywhere -

Comment: I think this [Link](https://github.com/weaveworks/weave/issues/3124#issuecomment-397820940) can help you.